# Pen cursor in Xournal

Tags: xfce, wacom, ubuntu-studio

I use Xournal to give lectures and do various other tasks. So far it's taken a little adjustment to write using my wacom tablet but it works fantastically.

My only complaint is the cursor. Xournal appears to override the system defined cursor with a dot cursor. The dot cursor is too small for me to reliably see. Is there a way to adjust the size of the cursor or even give it a different icon?

I've checked the user manual

http://xournal.sourceforge.net/manual.html

---

My system:
ubuntu studio 12.04
xfce desktop
xournal: 0.4.6~pre20110721-1build1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If anyone else is still having trouble with this, you can change the cursor type in settings now.

For Xournal++:

*Edit* > *Preferences* > *View* > *Cursor*

For the original Xournal:

*Options* > *Pencil Cursor*

Comment: Truth! 7 years ago when I asked this question said feature didn't exist

Comment: CAVEAT EMPTOR.  This answer is not about Xournal (not updated since 2016) but about its non official descendant, Xournal++.

Comment: @gboffi okay for vanilla options > pencil cursor. So caveat emptor indeed

Answer (score 4):

I found the following work around from 2010:

change the following lines in ~/.xournal/config

```
highlighter_opacity=.99
startup_tool=highlighter
highlighter_color=black
highlighter_thicknesses=0.85;1.41;2.26
```

This changes the default tool to highlighter, makes the color black, opaque and gives it the same thicknesses as the pen tool.

Here's where this was suggested:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xournal/forums/forum/554376/topic/3867709?message=8665099

Maybe I should submit a feature request.

Comment: This change is *so* much better.     Microscopic cursor has been driving me crazy.      I know 4 years have elapsed but you should definitely submit a feature request!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that this method doesn't seem to support "pressure sensitivity", so it's not really an option if you use and rely on a pen with such a capability.